# Making a multi-plot from an sf object using and displaying one unique color key

Tags: r-sf

Is it possible to make a multi-plot from an sf object, using and displaying one unique color key for all the subplots?

Answer (score 1):

The default of an `sf` object is a multi-plot of all the attributes, if that is what you mean, as described in `sf` [vignette 5](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf5.html).  Is this achieving what you are looking for?

`r
library(sf)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
plot(nc[,1:4], pal = sf.colors(10))`